# Date going to 1 April 2013 instead of 31 March 2013

Tags: javascript, date

I have these two functions that creates a new string in the correct format (`mm-dd-yyyy`) but right now it seems to not work so well... when I input the date `31-03-2013` which is a valid date, it comes out with `04-01-2013` as in the first of the month after....

Here are the two functions:

```
Date.prototype.sqlDate = Date.prototype.sqlDate || function () {
    return this.getMonth() + "-" + this.getDate() + "-" + this.getFullYear();
};

String.prototype.sqlDate = String.prototype.sqlDate || function () {
    var date = new Date(0);
    var s = this.split("-");
    //If i log "s" here its output is: 
    //    ["31", "03", "2013", max: function, min: function]
    date.setDate(s[0]);
    date.setMonth(s[1]);
    date.setYear(s[2]);
    return date.sqlDate();
};
```

Comment: Remember that JavaScript will return a 0-based month value, whereas date and year will be one-based. So January will be 0.

Comment: Oh buggers. Forgot this.

Comment: This "feature" of Javascript is one of the dumbest design decisions I've ever come across.

Comment: Agreed, if they are going to do it... might as well do them all... or none, not just the month -.-

Comment: @Pekka웃, I  wish I could say the same. I've seen even worse, the way the context changes to the window when you call a function, dumbest.

Comment: Even weirder problem now..... When not using this... it works fine for any date other then the 31st.... sooo.......

Comment: As in not using parseInt(s[1]) - 1

Comment: there isn't 31 on April 2013.

Comment: I know this... read my edit?

Comment: Man. I am out of it. Sorry. Still wasn't thinking in the 0 month.

Comment: So, is the problem finally solved?

Comment: Yesm. Sorry. Forgot to accept.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20806052/1048572

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Month of Date is a number between 0-Jan and 11-Dec,

So 3 is April...

It's extremely annoying because:

- **day**- 1 to 31. one based index
- **month**- 0 to 11. zero based index.

Well... javascript's specs... carry on.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

You can use this to set it right:

```
date.setMonth(parseInt(s[1], 10) - 1);
```

You can see it works here :

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
String.prototype.sqlDate = String.prototype.sqlDate || function () {
    var date = new Date(0);
    var s = this.split("-");
    //If i log "s" here its output is: 
    //    ["31", "03", "2013", max: function, min: function]
    date.setDate(s[0]);
    date.setMonth(parseInt(s[1],10)-1);
    date.setYear(s[2]);
    return date.sqlDate();
};
```